# how do i play 3d games on my tv from my laptop?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, hdmi, tv, 3d

i have [this](http://www.laptopmag.com/review/laptops/dell-xps-17-3d.aspx) Dell 3D laptop.
i have [this](http://www.samsung.com/us/video/tvs/UN65F9000AFXZA) Samsung 3D TV. (including 3d glasses, hdmi, bluray player, anything)

How can i play 3D games (that require 3D glasses) from the laptop, on my Samsung TV Screen, and what do i need?

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 HDMI on your TV according to your link and 1 one the laptop.  Get a HDMI cable and connect the 2 devices.  Then if you can find a game with 3d support you should be all set.  Your laptop has the nvidia 555 graphics which may not be powerful enough to run at 1920x1080 @120hz(60hz for each eye).  That is your only weakness.  Get a hdmi cable and try it, but be prepared to turn down the graphics quality to keep the speed up.